# Strange behavior of dashed lines with +(coord)

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why does the first dashed `\draw` work here, whereas the second does not?

The only difference is a coordinate (`-3` instead of `-2`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    mynodeok/.style={draw, font=\large,
        text height=1.75ex, text depth=.5ex,
        minimum height=4.5ex}    
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[mynodeok] {p};
        \node[mynodeok] (vd1) at (1,0) {vd};
        \draw[dashed] (vd1.base) -- +(-3,0) -- +(1,0);
        \node[mynodeok] at (0,-1) {p};
        \node[mynodeok] (vd2) at (1,-1) {vd};
        \draw[dashed] (vd2.base) -- +(-2,0) -- +(1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would guess pure unluck. You have two overlapping dashed lines. In the first case the dashes are quite aligned but in the second they are not. Try to remove the first `--`to get `\draw[dashed] (vd2.base)  +(-2,0) -- +(1,0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As StefanH commented, it was pure unluck.

By default the dashed path is defined: `on 3pt off 3pt` and this pattern is applied to the complete path. The count for on or off starts at path origin and finishes at its end, it doesn't matter how it is defined.

A simple example:

```
\draw[dashed] (0,0) rectangle ++(18pt,18pt); 
\draw[dashed] (25pt,0) rectangle ++(13pt,13pt);
```

produces

[image]

On left rectangle, as side length is multiple of 3, the dashed pattern is uniform, while on right rectangle you can see how `on 3pt` fragments start on one side and turn the corner.

This is what happen in your code.

You defined the dashed path with `\draw[dashed] (vd1.base) -- +(-3,0) -- +(1,0);` which means draw a dashed line from `vd1.base` until a relative coordinate `(-3cm,0)` and, from there, continue drawing the dashed pattern until another relative coordinate `(1,0)` also from `vd1.base`.

In this particular case, the left most dash is 1.5pt wide and when it turns to the right, all `on` fragments are ones over the others.

On the second path (`\draw[dashed] (vd2.base) -- +(-2,0) -- +(1,0);`) you are not so lucky. The left most fragment is almost 3pt wide, so when pen turns to right it draws `off` and following `on` covers the previous space.

As a solution, you can follow StefanH suggestion and draw the continuous path  `(vd2.base)+(-2,0) -- +(1,0)` (red lines in following figure)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    mynodeok/.style={draw, font=\large,
        text height=1.75ex, text depth=.5ex,
        minimum height=4.5ex}    
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[mynodeok] {p};
        \node[mynodeok] (vd1) at (1,0) {vd};
        \draw[dashed] (vd1.base) -- +(-3,0) -- +(1,0);
         \draw[dashed, red] ([yshift=-2pt]vd1.base) +(-3,0) -- +(1,0);

        \node[mynodeok] at (0,-1) {p};
        \node[mynodeok] (vd2) at (1,-1) {vd};
        \draw[dashed] (vd2.base) -- +(-2,0)--+(1,0);
        \draw[dashed, red] ([yshift=-2pt]vd2.base) +(-2,0) -- +(1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

At the left side of the `vd` nodes, the dashed lines overlap. The first case is lucky, that the lines and gap match, but in the second case, the gaps are filled by the overlapping line segments.

The coordinate calculations translate to:

```
(1, y) -- (-1 or -2, y) -- (1, y) -- (2, y)
```

Comment: Heiko, sorry, I don't understand the translation, could you write it with respect to `vd2.base`?

Comment: @CarLaTeX  Only the first coordinate is of interest for the horizontal line. Replace `y` with any vertical position. With respect to `vd2.base`, `(1, y)` can be rewritten as `(1, 0 |- vd2.base)`.  The expression `(-1 or -2, y)` means `(-1, y)` or `(-2, y)`.

Comment: The role of `y` is clear. Also the meaning of `(-1 or -2, y)`. What I didn't understand  was the `(1, y)`s and also why `-1` and `-2` instead of `-2` and `-3`.

Comment: @CarLaTeX `vd1` and `vd2` are centered at x=1, then `-3` and `-2` are subtracted with the result of `-2` and `-1`.

Comment: Ah, now it's clear, the (1, y) is the coordinate of the `vd` nodes, thank you!